Kullback-Leibler divergence. Is it true that: $D(\mathbb{P}_{f \circ X},\mathbb{P}_{f \circ \tilde{X}}) \le D(\mathbb{P}_X,\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}})$?
Suppose that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$, $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F}_X)$ and $ (\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{Y}})$ are measurable spaces.
Suppose that $X,\tilde{X}$ are measurable maps from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F}_X)$.
Suppose that $\varphi$ is a measurable map from $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F}_X)$ to $ (\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{F}_Y)$.
Assume that $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.
Consider the Kullback-Leibler divergences $$\mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_X,\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}) := \int_{\mathcal{X}} \ln \bigg(\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}}(x)\bigg) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X(x)\;,$$
and
$$\mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X},\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}) := \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \ln \bigg(\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}}(y)\bigg) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}(y)\;,$$
where $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}$ are the push-forward measures defined of $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{X}})$ by $\mathbb{P}_X[A] := \mathbb{P}[X\in A]$ and  $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde X}[A] := \mathbb{P}[\tilde{X}\in A]$, for each $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{X}}$, respectively, where $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}$ are the push-forward measures defined of $(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{Y}})$ by $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}[B] := \mathbb{P}[\varphi \circ X\in B]$ and  $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde X}[B] := \mathbb{P}[\varphi \circ \tilde{X}\in B]$, for each $B \in \mathcal{F}_{\mathcal{Y}}$, respectively, while $\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}} : \mathcal{X} \to [0,+\infty]$ is the Radon-Nikodyn derivative of $\mathbb{P}_X$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}$ and $\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}} : \mathcal{Y} \to [0,+\infty]$ is the Radon-Nikodyn derivative of $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}$.

Is it true that $$\mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X},\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}) \le \mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_X,\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}})\;?$$

Intuitively, at least from an information theoretic point of view, I expect this to be true, since the Kullback-Leibler divergence measure the "discrepancies" between two measures, and it seems plausible that a deterministic transformation can only decrease this discrepancy.
In fact, this is true at least when $\varphi(X)$ and $\varphi(\tilde{X})$ are discrete random variables and $\mathbb{P}_X$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}$ are absolutely continuous with respect to each other, given that
\begin{align}
   \mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X},\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}})
&=
   \int_{\mathcal{Y}} \ln \bigg(\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ \tilde{X}}}(y)\bigg) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\varphi \circ X}(y)
\\
&=
   \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \ln \bigg(\frac{\mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]}{\mathbb{P}[\tilde{X} \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]}\bigg) \mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]
\\
&=
   \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} -\ln \bigg(\frac{\mathbb{P}[\tilde{X} \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]}{\mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]}\bigg) \mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]
\\
&=
   \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} -\ln \bigg(\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]} \int_{\varphi^{-1}(y)} \frac{\operatorname{d} \mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}}{\operatorname{d} \mathbb{P}_{X}}(x) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X (x)\bigg) \mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]
\\
&\le
   \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} \bigg(\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]} \int_{\varphi^{-1}(y)} -\ln \bigg( \frac{\operatorname{d} \mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}}{\operatorname{d} \mathbb{P}_{X}}(x) \bigg) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X (x)\bigg) \mathbb{P}[X \in \varphi^{-1}(y)]
\\
&=
\int_{\mathcal{X}} \ln \bigg(\frac{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X}{\operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}}}(x)\bigg) \operatorname{d}\mathbb{P}_X(x)
\\
&=
\mathcal{D}_{\text{KL}}(\mathbb{P}_X,\mathbb{P}_{\tilde{X}})
\end{align}
where the inequality follows from the fact that $-\ln$ is a convex function and Jensen's inequality.

However, how should we proceed in the general case when $\varphi(X)$ and $\varphi(\tilde{X})$ are not discrete and we can't leverage the sum trick?


Does this answer your question? Why does relative entropy decrease under pushforward? See  here for example.

More generally, this decrease holds under any stochastic map (i.e.,  $D(\kappa \circ P| \kappa \circ \tilde{P}) \le D(P|\tilde{P}),$ where $\kappa$ is a Markov kernel), and for any $f$-divergence. This is known as the data processing inequality, and you can look the proof up, e.g., in Ch.7 of this book.
